# Pane. A minimal site specific Browser

Tags: python-3.x, gui, pyqt

Here is the code. It takes an argument with the `-l` flag for a link otherwise it goes to a hard coded search engine (I have selected brave to be different).

I'm looking for suggestions for improvement and maybe ways I can improve web page rendering and video playback.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import argparse


class Pane(QMainWindow):
    """Class to build the Site specific Browser"""
    def __init__(self, qrl):
        super(Pane, self).__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(1280, 720)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('hidive.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle(f"{qrl} - Pane")

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        try:
            self.browser.load(QUrl(qrl))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--link", default="https://search.brave.com", help="hyperlink to access")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    qrl = args.link

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName(f"{qrl} - Pane")
    window = Pane(qrl)

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you Sam! I wanted to upvote your edit but couldn't figure out how. (I need to get better at stack exchange)

Comment: While that is flattering, an edit cannot be upvoted. Voting applies to [questions and answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) (as well as comments).

Comment: Good to know! I'm so used to lurking and not commenting or posting. I'll learn.